# Codeigniter MY_Controller does not load header/footer.php

Tags: codeigniter

I am a newbie. I could finally make my site show the page with  MY_Controller.php except   footer and header part.

Here is my MY_Controller.php:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

  protected $data = array();

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function render_page($view) {
    //do this to don't repeat in all controllers...
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
    //menu_data must contain the structure of the menu...
    //you can populate it from database or helper

    $this->load->view($view, $this->data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $this->data);
  }
```

And my home controller :

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {
         function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

        public function view($page = 'home')
        {
         $this->load->helper('text');
            $data['records']= $this->services_model->getAll();
            if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter


            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);


        }
```

config/config.rb:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

config/routes.rb :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/view/$1';
```

In the source code , I can only see the home.php codes. The header and footer.php codes are not loaded. What are your suggestions?

Comment: I also develop in Ruby on rails :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Home` Controller you're loading the view directly, instead of using `render_page` function.

So, change:

`$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data)`

To:

`$this->render_page('pages/'.$page);`

Hopefully, this will load the header/footer.